# Azure: Deploy a file that is not part of the solution

Tags: model-view-controller, deployment, azure

I have a file that I want to deploy when my web project (an ASP.NET MVC project) is deployed, however I want to remove that file from the solution (it's a very large CSS file that slows down my solution and crashes VS if I open it by mistake).

Is there a way to make the Azure project include this file so it is added to the package to deploy?

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine that fact that your crashing the ide, maybe you should rethink the approach ?

Comment: The problem is that VS has a very bad handling of very long lines and since the CSS is a minified CSS that I just use to deploy to the site I don't think I have to rethink the approach. It doesn't really crash, just takes like 5 mins to open whenever I try to open it by mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to add a BeforeBuild ItemGroup in the project file that will add it.  To do that, try the following:

1. Right click on the MVC project and select Edit Project File
2. Go towards the bottom of that file and uncomment the <Target Name="BeforeBuild"></Target>
3. Make that target look like the following, using your own file name and path:

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">

<ItemGroup><Content Include="Content\Site2.css" />
</ItemGroup>

</Target>

4.  Save and reload the project file

Now when you package the Azure project including the MVC project, the content that was added in the BeforeBuild target should be in the package.

Comment: What path did you use for the Include?  When i was playing with it, i found that if it is wrong, there is no error - just doesn't include it.  Otherwise you could add a message task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx) in the target to output something in order to verify it is at least running the target.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that might be useful would be to serve this CSS file out of Azure BLOB storage instead of out of the web role. I suspect it doesn't change that often?

By using the BLOB store you can easily turn on the CDN (easier to deal with than from web role).

You could then include absolute URL references back to this file from your project master pages.

If you want to be *really* clever you could include the non minified content in your VS project for easy editing and then Minify and upload to BLOB storage as part of your MSBuild script.

Comment: Actually the file is changing frequently right now, and I'm not using BLOB storage right now (I will consider it once we are live). I guess I'll just stick with having the css in the solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a startup cmd to your Service Definition that copies the CSS from blob storage to your approot as the instance starts up.  Here's some powershell for you:

Startup.cmd: 
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell .\get-file.ps1

get-file.ps1:
$obj = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$path = "e:\approot\"
$url = "http://.blob.core.windows.net//"
$obj.DownloadFile ($url, $path)

This takes a few seconds to copy the file, basically at LAN speeds.

And a link to MSDN if you haven't done startup cmd before:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx

Comment: But this would mean that I have to add some kind of task that deploys the CSS file to BLOB storage which will make things even more complex. I'm not using BLOB storage right now and I don't want to start using it yet.